# Using setjmp in a wrapper function and local variable clobbering

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, standard-library, setjmp

The setjmp(3) documentation in the manpages (on my system) states that

> All accessible objects have values as of the time longjmp() routine was called, except that the values of objects of automatic storage invocation duration that do not have the volatile type and have been
>        changed between the setjmp() invocation and longjmp() call are indeterminate.

Does this include only the objects which are in the same scope as the function that calls `setjmp`, or also any objects in the scope of functions higher up the callstack?

For example, is the following code correct?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

jmp_buf env;

void function_that_longjmps(void)
{
    longjmp(env, 1);
}

int setjmp_wrapper(jmp_buf env)
{
    if (setjmp(env) == 0)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}

int main()
{
    int i = 0;

    if (setjmp_wrapper(env) == 0) {
        i = 1;
        function_that_longjmps();
    }

    printf("i = %d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

The local variable `i` gets modified between the `setjmp` and `longjmp` calls, but it does not exist in the scope of the `setjmp_wrapper`. Is there a possibility for the variable to get clobbered in this case?

Comment: Trying to `longjmp` into `setjmp_wrapper` after it's already returned is undefined behavior by itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example exhibits undefined behavior regardless of what happens to local variables, because you can't `longjmp` into a function execution that has already returned.

As for an example that doesn't exhibit UB, perhaps

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

jmp_buf env;

void calls_longjmp(int *p) {
    *p = 1;
    longjmp(env);
}
void calls_setjmp(int *p) {
    if (setjmp(env)) {
        return;
    }
    calls_longjmp(p);
}
int main(void) {
    int x = 0;
    calls_setjmp(&x);
    printf("%d\n", x);
}
```

then `x` is guaranteed to have value `1`, not `0` or indeterminate, after the `longjmp`. Quoting the [C11 N1570 draft](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.13.2.1p3):

> All accessible objects have values, and all other components of the abstract machine<sup>249)</sup> have state, as of the time the longjmp function was called, except that the values of objects of automatic storage duration **that are local to the function containing the invocation of the corresponding setjmp macro** that do not have volatile-qualified type and have been changed between the setjmp invocation and longjmp call are indeterminate.

Comment: Thanks, I did not realize my code had other undefined behaviour.